# Does a Legacies's Primary Arcanum become a the Ruling Arcanum for the joining mage?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, mage-the-awakening

I have found some reference to this online.
I would like to confirm it, as I've not see the ruling in books themselves:

*The primary arcanum in a legacy from my understanding also turns into the ruling arcanum for the mage who joins the legacy.*

Is this true? If so, which book/page is the ruling regarding it located?

Is this an additional perk, beyond the legacy's attainments, that all legacies provide?

Comment: This needs an edition tag: either [chronicles-of-darkness-1e] (i.e. nWoD, from White-Wolf) or   [chronicles-of-darkness-2e] (i.e. nWoD-2e, CoD, GMC-RU... from Onyx Path).

Comment: I am guessing **1e**, as otherwise it should have been using the **2e** tag for mage also.

Comment: Yep, this is a 1E question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct.

The rule is found in the Mage the Awakening corebook, page 345, fifth bullet point under "Advantages of Attainments"

> Some legacies have attainments that utilise a primary Arcanum other than the parent Path's Ruling Arcanum
>
> ...
>
> The Legacy's primary Arcanum can be learned as if it were a Ruling Arcanum
>
> ...
>
> In addition, the required Mana point normally required for improvised casting is not spent when using that Arcanum

Technically it is not a Ruling arcanum, but I cannot find any advantage a Ruling arcanum gives that this doesn't, so it is effectively a third Ruling Arcanum.

Comment: Thank you, I've been looking all over for the ruling on this, appearently it was under "attaiment advantages"... Which is a bit weird since that piece of information isn't really apart of attaiments.

Comment: Yeah, it took me a while to find it.  It was a rule I had just internalised without noticing.